# How to check for state and do something in an RXJS observable stream Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to set form validators of my Angular reactive form based on the state of a BehaviourSubject of RXJS without subscribing to it instead using RXJS map operator but it isn't working as follows:

```
this.form_type$.pipe(
      map((type) => {
        if (type === 'signup') {
          this.auth_form
            ?.get('email')
            ?.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.email]);
          this.auth_form
            ?.get('password')
            ?.setValidators([
              Validators.required,
              Validators.minLength(8),
              Validators.pattern(
                `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()|:;'"><,./?_=+-]).{8,}$`
              ),
            ]);
        } else {
          this.auth_form?.get('email')?.setValidators([]);
          this.auth_form?.get('password')?.setValidators([]);
        }
      })
    );
```

But it works fine if it is subscribed:

```
this.form_type$.subscribe((type) => {
  if (type === 'signup') {
    this.auth_form
      ?.get('email')
      ?.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.email]);
    this.auth_form
      ?.get('password')
      ?.setValidators([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.pattern(
          `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()|:;'"><,./?_=+-]).{8,}$`
        ),
      ]);
  } else {
    this.auth_form?.get('email')?.setValidators([]);
    this.auth_form?.get('password')?.setValidators([]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline **will NOT** be created untill your subscribe to it.

Did you subscribe anywhere to that pipe in the first snippet?

```
this.form_type$.pipe(
      map((type) => { 
          //your stuff
      })
    ).subscribe(//now pipe will be created and it might start working);
```

without `subscribe` it is just a static unreachable code.

Comment: Understand that, but it will kind of defeat the purpose of using a pipe since I'll have to unsubscribe from it, right?

Comment: I see no point of using `map` here since you want to react to `this.form_type$` changes and you dont need to process futher whatever you are doing in `map`. Since it is the only thing you want to do, do it in `subscribe`

Comment: Sorry, I might misunderstand you. Does your answer require unsubscribing after use?

Comment: You should always unsubscribe or terminate pipeline